# Customizing Field Visibility on existing Account Records for different System Administrator Users without changing their profile

Tags: fields, configuration

Description:

Hi Salesforce Community,

I'm facing a challenge regarding field visibility on existing  Account records for users with the same System Administrator profile. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

Objective:

I have a account record Acc1 with fields that need to be selectively visible to two different System Administrator users. For example, I want Field1 to be visible only to User1 and Field2 to be visible only to User2, while both users share the same System Administrator profile and I have only 2 salesforce licenses and only 2 users.

Questions:

Is there a native Salesforce feature or configuration option that can achieve this level of field visibility differentiation?
If not, what would be the best approach to implement this custom solution using Visualforce or Lightning Components?

Any insights, suggestions, or guidance on how to approach this customization challenge would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove field visibility from the System Administrator profile, you can then create a Permission Set, assign the relevant field to each Permission Set, and then assign each User to each Permission Set. Note, however, that administrators can always just add field security back to their profile, so the solution is basically on the honor system.